# 'History.statechange' fires during document.ready in IE9

Tags: jquery, history.js

I have a webpage that uses history.js to perform some tasks based on the hash change.

I use replaceState to change the history state.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    History.replaceState("state =1", "title", "?querystring");

    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
        var State = History.getState();
        if (State.title == "title")
            window.location.href = "default.aspx?mode=1";
        else
            window.location.href = "default.aspx?mode=2";
    });
});
```

However the 'statechange' event is called on 'document.ready' as well as browser's back/forward button in IE9. But in chrome and safari, it works fine by calling only when browser's back/forward is clicked.

Since am reloading the page based on title. IE goes crazy by reloading the page continuously.

I went through all possible forums and threads regarding the issue. But none of the solution worked.

Please suggest any workaround to call 'statechange' event only on back/forward button click that works in IE9 as well as in other browsers.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please post your pushState code also. I dont know what is the use of replaceState here.

Comment: I use only replacestate. My site has many pages, In one page, i load different content dynamically based on the  querystring. So, that page is given two different title based on content, And i'll reload the page when back button is clicked. If i use pushState, i encounter a problem of not going to previous page at all since the current page is keep on loading. With replaceState, my site works fine in chrome and safari but not IE9 and mozilla. Also In mozilla and IE, 'State.title' returns empty when i click back/forward button. whereas chrome and safari returns the previous title correctly.

Comment: try replacing state.title with state.data, And you manually update the title from state.data.

Comment: Since no answer or attention was received so far, i removed history plugin and applied some old school workaround. My site works fine now.